# Grammar and aspect of 「コーヒー飲んでき！」

Tags: grammar, verbs, dialects, aspect, morphology

I have some questions about 「コーヒー飲んでき！」

1. What is it a contraction of ?
2. Is it inchoative ?
3. In all of the examples i've found, it's an invitation to come in.

But i think 「コーヒー飲んでき」can mean [ Why don't you go out,  take a walk, and have a cup of coffee in a coffee shop. You'll feel better afterwards. ]

Could someone confirm this ?  and/or find a sample from the net, book ... ?

<sub>「お姉さん！お茶飲んでき！！」</sub>

..... 君、コーヒー飲んでき～」と声をかけられ

、「ほなコレだけ飲んでき！」と、ビールを一杯 ご馳走頂き…

見知らぬお姉さん  ... 「 ここのお酒、おいしいから飲んでき～！」と声をかけられ ...

..... サービスするしここで飲んでき～～！」と言って店の前にテーブルと椅子が準備されました♪

Comment: Isn't it just  < 飲んできて < 飲んできてください, using 来る as an auxiliary verb? If so, I can see both senses: "please come [in here] to drink", and "please go drink and come [back]".

Answer (score 10):

1. Here in all of your examples, it's a contraction of 飲んでいき～ (飲んで行きい) in regional dialect mainly used in the Kansai area, meaning 飲んでいけ (飲んで + subsidiary verb 行け), or 飲んでいって(ちょうだい), literally "(Please) Drink and go."

   This colloquial contraction (dropping い in the subsidiary verb 行く) is also seen in Standard Japanese:

   > 飲んで**い**く → 飲んでく  
   >   走って**い**こう。 → 走ってこう。 / 走ってこ。
   >   持って**い**け！ → 持ってけ！
   >   買って**い**って。 → 買ってって。
   >   予習して**い**かなくていいの？ → 予習してかなくていいの？
2. I don't think so... (in your examples, at least).
3. Yes, 飲んできー can also mean 飲んで[来]{き}い, which is 飲んで[来]{こ}い / 飲んできて(ちょうだい) in Standard Japanese.

   > - [飲んで(い)き(い)]{LLHHHHHHHH} / [飲んで(い)き(い)さ]{LLHHHHHLLLL} -- 飲んでいけ Drink here and go. / Drink before you go.
   > - [飲んできい]{LLHLH} / [飲んできいさ]{LLHHLL} / [飲んできいさ]{LLHLLL} etc. -- 飲んでこい (Go) Drink and come back.

Other examples:

「～てきい」 as 「～てこい」:

> - はよ取ってきい(な)。 -- 早く取ってこい/きて(よ)
>     Fetch it and come back now. / Go and get it now.
> - 持ってきい(さ)。 -- 持ってこい/きて(よ)
>     Bring it here.
> - しっかり勉強してきい(や)。 -- しっかり勉強してこい(よ)/きて(ね)/きなさい(よ)
>     Go study hard and come back. / Study hard over there.

「～てきい」 as 「～ていけ」:

> - 食べてきい(な)。-- 食べていけ/いって(よ)
>     Eat here and go. / Eat before you go.
> - 持ってき。-- 持っていけ/いって/いきなさい
>     Take it with you.
> - ちゃんと用意してき(や)。 -- ちゃんと用意していけ(よ)/いって(ね)/いきなさい(よ)
>     Prepare thoroughly before you go.

Comment: 100%関西弁オンリーか？と言われると、例えば中国地方や四国には関西弁に似た表現がたくさんありますし、今回の「食べてき」も関西以外で全く使われていないとは言い切れませんので、「主に関西で使われてる方言」に変更させていただきました。

Answer (score 1):

「コーヒー飲んでき」 is a contraction of 「コーヒーを飲んで行き（なさい）」－ Have a cup of coffee.

「....してき」 is often used in such a way as "ちょっと、寄ってき(ちょっと立ち寄って行きなさい) - Have a drop at (the shop) - a solicitation phrase often heard from barkers of red-light corners. "そこへ置いとき(置いておきなさい) - Just leave it there," "気を付けてき(気を付けて行きなさい) - Take care," and "早く帰ってき(早く帰ってきなさい）- Come back soon."

I'm Kyushu-ite. But, I've never heard of this turn of phrase in my hometown. I think I often heard it in Kansai-area, but I'm not sure where it is spoken widely.

Answer (score 0):

この 「コーヒー飲んでき！」 って関西弁オンリー？

東京では全く使わん？　理解も出来ん？

「ちょっと読んで見い」　とか と変わらん感じもするが。

- 岐阜--- nawan13.hatenablog.com/entry/2015/09/02/123540 -- ‎2015年 ... 初めて参加した「岐阜の地酒に酔う」で御代櫻醸造のブース前で、見知らぬお姉さんが「ここのお酒、おいしいから飲んでき～！」と声をかけられ、杜氏に「お薦めをお願いします 。」と言っていただいたのがきっかけなんです。あの時、お姉さんに声 ...
- 長野県(?) --- sanadaen.blog9.fc2.com/blog-entry-329.html -- 2011年 ...  枝垂れ桃（白） 真っ白で、心が洗われます。 ジョギングコースにある知り合いの家の木朝から、「お茶飲んでき～」と言われます。  ...
- 福島・茨城巡り～！？ minkara.carview.co.jp/userid/410696/car/1056202/.../photo.aspx -- 2016年 ... 喜多方から峠道を越え・・ ... 氷柱も、 去年よりインパクトが低かったです。... お茶でも飲んでき～と、ご馳走になったお店。

Comment: `関西弁オンリー？` -> 四国や東北でも使われるかもしれませんが、知らないのではっきりとはわかりません。`東京では全く使わん？` -> 純粋な東京弁では現れないと思います。`理解も出来ん？`-> 絶対できます。`「ちょっと読んで見い」とかと変‌​わらん感じもするが`-> 関西では「[飲んでいきい]{LLHHHH}」「[飲んできい]{LLHLH}」「[読んでみい]{LLHLH}」などとなりますが‌​、

Comment: (cont.) 関東は「[読んでみい]{HLLHL}」‌で、少なくともこのパターンの「[飲んできい]{HLLHL}」は標準語にはありません。（アクセントに関わらず、「飲んできい」自体、東京で使われるかどうかもちょっと疑問ですが。）なお、二つ目のリンクのブログで、ご近所さ‌​んにいつも「飲んでき～」と言われるという場所は‌​、長野県ではなく岩手県ですね。約20年間‌​長野で育ち、その後岩手に嫁いで約30年間‌​になるということが書かれていますので。

Comment: P.S. 三つ目のブログのリンクが壊れてます。直してもらえませんか。

Comment: 中四国でごく普通に使われ、関東地方ではかなり稀だと思いますが、東北のことはよく分かりません。